# What does C stand for in JDeveloper 12c?

Tags: java

Can any one say what does the letter C stand for in the IDE JDeveloper 12c ?
I am unable to find the exact extension.

Comment: Do you really care ?

Comment: Yes, if you know then let me know.

Comment: @ManikantaReddy, without a citation of some sort, I'm going to assume you've just made up some rubbish :-) In any case (and this is more to the OP), I hardly see how this info is going to be useful to anyone.

Comment: Is that an official ?

Comment: @rakesh Have some respect towards your answerers, you already have  an answer and still asking question ?

Comment: @paxdiablo What you want to tell now for answer posted for this question? Still that link is rubbish ?

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes. That is the least bothered info that any one want. But That's not rubbish which spoke by Manikanta. That's true, but without a citation.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Thanks for the assist in quoting the link.

Comment: @Andreas You should thank for that upvote too ;)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Thank you for your suggestion. I didn't disrespect anyone. Just I needed official information on it. In case if it seems my disrespect to anyone, really I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for "cloud". See Wikipedia about [Oracle Version Numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#Version_numbering).

> The suffixes "i", "g" and "c" do not actually represent a low-order part of the version number, as letters typically represent in software industry version numbering; that is, there is no predecessor version of Oracle 10g called Oracle 10f. Instead, the letters stand for "internet", "grid" and "**cloud**", respectively.[70] Consequently, many simply drop the "g" or "i" suffix when referring to specific versions of an Oracle product.

The link `[70]` is a reference to the `theregister.co.uk` article "[Oracle gears up for infrastructure cloud and 12c database launches](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/09/20/oracle_openworld_preview_q1_f2012_numbers/)":

> Oracle 12c will sport features for secure multi-tenancy within a single database instance – something that Ellison has bashed as an idea in the past. It will be "**cloud**-enabled" - just as Oracle 9i was "Internet ready" and Oracle 10g and 11g were "grid-enabled,". In other words 12c could be clustered.

Comment: I always thought that `i`, `g` and `c` stood for `inadequate`, `garbage` and `crap`, though that may just be due to my opinion of a company that can't seem to tell the difference between an empty string and a NULL :-)

Comment: That is pointing to Database section. Do you have any links which points to JDeveloper 12c with version details ?

Comment: @rakesh The version naming scheme applies across Oracle products. As you can see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/jdev-history-099970.html): 10g, 11 g, 12c.

Comment: @rakesh You should at least accept his answer for wasting his time on this.